# unreachable statement, recursion (java)

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to solve a simple problem, take a string and reverse the order of the words in the string. My code is as follows:

```
public class reverse
{
public static String rev (String a){
    String[] arr = a.split(" ");
    int count = arr.length;
    String result;
    if (count <= 1){
        result = arr[count];
        return result;
    }else{
        String temp = arr[count];
        return temp;
        result = rev(temp);
        count --;
    }
  }
}
```

My dilemma is that upon compiling I get an error on the 13th line stating "unreachable statement". In terms of recursion I do not see an issue, but any help for solving this problem would be appreciated.

NOTE: I am aware there is no main method, I am using the BlueJ IDE in which I can test individual methods.

Comment: You cannot have code after a `return` statement

Comment: What do you think happens when your program executes `return` statement?

Comment: `result = rev(temp); count --;` These lines are dead code and won't be executed because your method will have already returned. Those lines are unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return` for your `else` block **after** you recurse. Also, arrays start at `0` and contain `length - 1` elements. You could do something like,

```
int count = arr.length - 1;
if (count < 1) {
    result = arr[count];
} else { 
    String temp = arr[count];
    // return temp;
    result = temp + " " + rev(a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf(' ')));
    // count--; // <-- updates local count uselessly.
}
return result;
```

Comment: thank you for the edits! Unfortunately testing this just returns the last word in the phrase (e.g. "hello world" returns "world" instead of "world hello"

Comment: the non-base case needs to cons the result from the rev call onto the string

Comment: @NathanHughes just to clarify when you say cons do you mean concatenate?

Comment: @Arkadelic: yes, should've said concatenate. the non-base case has to build up the answer one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous comments, you need a solution that uses purely recursion. As such, try the following. Note that it is currently pretty fragile in the sense that it relies on the fact that words are separated by exactly one space character. But if you need a robust solution, we can certainly modify it. See the [demo on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/zbD2Bs).

```
public static String rev (String a){
    int firstSpace = a.indexOf(' ');
    boolean multipleWords = (firstSpace != -1);

    if (!multipleWords) {
        return a;
    } else {
        String firstWord = a.substring(0, firstSpace);
        String remainingWords = a.substring(firstSpace + 1, a.length());
        String reversedRemainingWords = rev(remainingWords);
        String reversedWords = reversedRemainingWords + " " + firstWord;
        return reversedWords;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised answer that uses substrings rather than splitting it into a string array. I haven't tested it, but I believe it will work as expected.

```
public class reverse {
    public static String rev (String a){
        String result = "";
        if(a.contains(' ')){
            int i = a.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1;
            result = a.substring(i) + " " + rev(a.substring(0, i-1));
        }
        else{
            result = a;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to be able to to solve the problem in a simple way such as this, except for the fact that the caveat of this problem is that I must use recursion...

Comment: Ah right, forgot about that. Seems like you may need a second method for the recursion part, since you try to use `String[]` but return `String`. If I think of something else, I'll revise this answer. Otherwise, I'll most likely delete it